# jQuery chat with append() doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, append, chat, prepend

I use this code for a kinda a chat.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#Send").click(function(){
              var tx=$("#ChtInput").text();
              $("#ChtShow").append("<br/><br/>"+tx);
            });
              });
</script>
```

**#Send** is a button,
**#ChtInput** is the text area from where you're introducing text
And when **#Send** is clicked, post the text into the **#ChtShow** div.
It works fine in IE, but in Chrome and Firefox it append just `<br/><br/>` tags

I made it work doing that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var tx=$("#ChtInput").text();
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Send").click(function(){
           $("#ChtShow").append("<br/><br/>"+tx);
            });
              });
```

But this way work only if i put some text between the textarea tags, but it show only the text between the texarea tags instead of what i write in the textarea.

Sorry for my english...I hope you understand :D

Comment: General tip: Improve your indentation. Things have to line up or they won't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use val() instead of text():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#Send").click(function(){
          var tx=$("#ChtInput").val();
          $("#ChtShow").append("<br/><br/>"+tx);
      });
  });
</script>
```